# PHP script no longer receiving data from context stream

Tags: php

We have a "legacy" script that stopped working a little while back. Pretty sure it's because the endpoint it's connecting to changed from http to https, and the old http address now returns a 301.

I've never done anything other than tiny changes to PHP scripts, so am a little out of my depth here.

Note that our PHP version is old - 5.3.0. This may well be part of  the problem.

The script as-is (relevant bit anyway):

```
$uri = "http://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx"
     ."?SelectDate=$date&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y";
$opts = array('http' => array(
                 'proxy' => 'tcp://internal.proxy.address:port',
                 'method' => 'GET',
                 'request_fulluri' => true)
              );
$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$lines = file($uri, false, $ctx);
foreach ($lines as $line)
...
```

This returns nothing any more. The link btw is the IMF link for exchange rates, so that is open to all - if you open it you'll get a download with a rate table in it. The rest of the script basically parses this for the data we want.

Now, pretty sure our proxy is OK. Running some tests with curl gives the following results:

```
curl --proxy tcp://internal.proxy.address:port -v https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx?SelectDate=05/28/2020&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y
```

(specify https) works just fine.

```
curl --proxy tcp://internal.proxy.address:port -v http://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx?SelectDate=05/28/2020&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y
```

(specify http) does not work, and shows a 301 error

```
curl --proxy tcp://internal.proxy.address:port -v -L http://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx?SelectDate=05/28/2020&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y
```

(specify http with follow redirects) then works OK.

I've tried a few things after some googling. It seems I need opts for 'ssl' as well when using https. So I've made the following changes

```
$uri = "https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx"
     ."?SelectDate=$date&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y";
$opts = array('http' => array(
                 'proxy' => 'tcp://internal.proxy.address:port',
                 'method' => 'GET',
                 'request_fulluri' => true),
              'ssl' => array(
                 'verify_peer' => false,
                 'verify_peer_name' => false,
                 'SNI_enabled' => false)
              );
```

Sadly, the `SNI_enabled` flag was introduced after 5.3.0, so I don't think this helps. There's also a `follow_location` context option for http, but that was introduced in 5.3.4, so also no use.

(BTW, I have little to no control over the version of PHP we have, so while I appreciate higher versions may offer better solutions, that's not a lot of use to me I'm afraid).

Basically, I am now stuck. No combination of these parameters or settings returns any data at all. I can see it works via curl and the proxy, so it's not a general connectivity issue.

Any and all suggestions gratefully received!

Update: After adding the lines to enable error reporting, the error code is for the stream connecting:

```
Warning: file(https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx?SelectDate=05/28/2020&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y): failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy in /usr/bass/apps/htdocs/BASS/mods/module.XSM.php on line 79
```

(line 79 is the `$lines = ...` line)

So it doesn't connect in the php script, but running the same connection via the proxy in curl works fine. What's the difference in php that causes this?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The script throws no error. I just see that if I interrogate $lines there's absolutely nothing there. Not entirely sure how to check what the error message is, or even if I'd do it when setting `$ctx` or calling `file`- I did say PHP is not my thing :) And I obviously failed in my googling when trying to look for this.

Comment: If you wanted to ask here, you'd first have to extract a [mcve] (well-formatted, please!) and provide that as part of your question. That said, hire a programmer: You say yourself you don't know PHP well and learning an ancient version is kind-of futile, hence that suggestion.

Comment: This is reproducible on PHP version 5.3 as far as I am aware.

Comment: You can view the error message by turning it on by adding these pieces of codes at the very beginning of this php file.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Remember to add them temporarily for debugging only and remove those from any production ready codes to prevent any security threats.

Comment: thanks @RakibulIslam. I added that and I've edited the question with the error messgae. It's an SSL connection issue, so the question is how to fix that in php version 5.3.0? Or even _if_ it can be solved in 5.3.0?

Comment: @urbanespaceman I guess you have no luck using PHP 5.3 to solve the problem in the way you are doing it. Have you tried using php curl functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php curl functions to get the response from your given url. And then you can use `explode()` function to break the response line by line.

```
$uri = "https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_mth.aspx"
     ."?SelectDate=$date&reportType=CVSDR&tsvflag=Y";

$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $uri,
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => 'tcp://internal.proxy.address:port',
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$lines = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$lines = explode("\n", $lines);    // breaking the whole response string line by line

foreach ($lines as $line)
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this on Monday when I'm back in work!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!!